# GridDB: How to handle 'Time-out occurred' error when executing operations in GridDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, griddb

During my interactions with a GridDB database using Node.js and the griddb-node package, I'm occasionally encountering a 'Time-out occurred' error. It seems to happen when executing long-running operations or queries. How can I handle this error and prevent the time-outs from occurring?

```js
const griddb = require('griddb-node');

try {
  const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
  const store = factory.getStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 31810,
    clusterName: 'defaultCluster',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
  });

  const container = store.getContainer('myContainer');
  
  // Set an extremely large timeout value
  container.setTimeout(60000); // 60 seconds

  // Perform operations on the container that might take a long time

  container.close();
  store.close();
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Time-out occurred error:', error);
}
```